# Controller retorna false e igualmente realiza operacion como si fuera true

Tags: php

Tengo un controlador que tiene un bug bastante fuerte, el controlador que la la alerta de Sweet Alert diciendo que los datos están repetidos corra igualmente incluso cuando no hay datos que esten repetidos en la base de datos

```
    public function añadirPais($datos){

    $pais = new paisesModel;

    $json = array();
    
    if($pais->getInfoPais($datos) != true){

        $json['msj'] = 'El pais ha sido añadido exitosamente'; 
        $json['success'] = true;
        echo json_encode($json);

        if($pais->addPais($datos) == true){

        
            $json['msj'] = 'El pais ha sido añadido exitosamente'; 
            $json['success'] = true;
            echo json_encode($json);

        }else{

            $json['msj'] = 'Error . No se pudo añadir el pais'; 
            $json['success'] = false;
            echo json_encode($json);

        }

    }else{

        $json['msj'] = 'Error . Alguno de los datos coincide con un pais'; 
        $json['success'] = false;
        echo json_encode($json);

    }


}
```

Aqui esta lo que corre el Modelo, es decir getInfoPais($nombre , $sigla , $prefijo). El problema diría que radica en la parte de return, ya que si no consigue datos deberia retornar NULL es decir false pero el controller no lo interpreta bien

```
public static function getInfoPais($nombre,$sigla,$prefijo){

        require '../require/Conexion.php';

        $sql = "SELECT ps.nombre_pais, ps.siglas_pais, ps.prefijo_pais 
        FROM ec_pais AS ps WHERE ps.nombre_pais = '$nombre' 
        OR ps.siglas_pais = '$sigla' OR ps.prefijo_pais = '$prefijo';";

        $result = @mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);// or die(mysqli_error($conn));

        if (!$result) {

               return null;

        }

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        mysqli_close ($mysqli);

        return $row;

}
```

Edicion, olvide colocar esto, que es el jquery on submit de la forma en si. Ojala sirva de algo

```
jQuery(document).on("submit", "#formCaddpais", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  datos = $(this).serializeArray();
  datos.push({ name: "opcion", value: "addPais" });
  jQuery
    .ajax({
      url: "../controllers/paisesController.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: datos,
    })
    .done(function (data) {
      var success = JSON.parse(data).success;
      var msj = JSON.parse(data).msj;
      if (success) {
        swal("¡Realizado!", msj, "success").then((value) => {
          location.href = "caddpais.php";
        });
      } else {
        swal("¡Error!", msj, "error");
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: `getInfoPais()` devuelve `null` o un arreglo, sin embargo comparas el resultado con `if($verificar_pais == true)`. Aparte, estás creando y cerrando una conexión a MySQL para cada consulta, a la larga te traerá problemas.

Comment: Buenas. Entonces que deberia hacer?

Comment: Hacer la comparación adecuada: `if($pais->getInfoPais($datos) === null) { /* Insertar país */ }`

Comment: En realidad ya solucione el problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuve que cambiar el JS porque insertaba y validaba dos veces

```
$('#formCaddpais').submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  datos = $(this).serializeArray();
  datos.push({ name: "opcion", value: "addPais" });
  jQuery
    .ajax({
      url: "../controllers/paisesController.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: datos,
    })
    .done(function (data) {
      var success = JSON.parse(data).success;
      var msj = JSON.parse(data).msj;
      if (success) {
        swal("¡Realizado!", msj, "success").then((value) => {
          location.href = "caddpais.php";
        });
      } else {
        swal("¡Error!", msj, "error");
      }
    });
});
```